# Put data into jQuery from MySQL

Tags: jquery, mysql

```
var words = ['boat', 'bear', 'dog', 'drink', 'elephant', 'fruit'];              
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#yourElement').autocomplete(
    hints: words
  );
});
```

I want to put data from mySQL database instead of `['boat', 'bear', 'dog', 'drink', 'elephant', 'fruit']`

Comment: Fetch data from database and store inside `var words` or directly call using AJAX

Comment: Good, Please show the code that you're trying to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

there's about a billion different ways to do this... a simple way.. which is easy to understand.. would be..

assuming you're using PHP.. create a PHP page that returns nothing but this:

```
var words = ['boat', 'bear', 'dog', 'drink', 'elephant', 'fruit'];
```

and then somewhere in your HTML create a script reference to that PHP page..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="returnwords.php"></script>
```

just make sure it will get executed before your code, since you're doing jquery document.ready you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

To followup @norlihazmey-ghazali comment

Option 1:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#yourElement').autocomplete(
    source: 'data.php'
  );
});
```

Option 1 data.php:

```
<?php
$words = array;
/* DB code adding values to $words array: $words[] = $value */
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($words);
?>
```

Option 2:

```
<?php
$words = array();
/* DB code adding values to $words array: $words[] = $value */
?>
var words = <?php echo json_encode($words);?>              
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#yourElement').autocomplete(
    hints: words
  );
});
```